# ContentView background colour Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

When I select a cell on a table view it by default changes it's ContentView background colour to a light grey and I am trying to override this.

And I am using the following code to remove this grey colour from the selection. But it is removing the background colour of everything (UIViews, UIImageViews) inside that cell.

Is there a way to eliminate the background colour of the ContentView only?

```
    let changeselectionColor = UIView()
    changeselectionColor.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = changeselectionColor
```

I have the following table view cell.

**This is how it should look like when selected**

[image]

**This is how it end up looking with all BGs transparent**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to override anything to achieve the effect, actually UITableViewCell provides the API to remove the highlight gray:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```